# Waterfall AJAX multiply requests (such as in wolframalafa)

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have this problem - I want to do multiply AJAX requests but I need that the second request will sent when the first successfully completed.

I try to use **jQuery Deffered** object, **jQuery.when()** and **jQuery.then()** methods, but...(((

At last I used this plugin - https://github.com/dio-el-claire/jquery.waterfall. But I couldn't do that. Because, as I understood, with this plugin all returned data output at the same time.

Such as in http://www.wolframalpha.com.

Thanks for advance!

*Sorry for my bad English)*

Answer (score 1):

use the success portion of the ajax call.  You can put a function there to deal with the returned data.  You can also deal with errors.

I'm doing this is pseudo-coffeescript, but hopefully it will make sense.

```
jQuery(() ->
  window.App = {};
  window.App.behaviors = [];
  window.App.behaviors.push(ComposableBehavior.new());
)

class ComposableBehavior(() ->
  getData: ((url,successFunction, errorFunction) ->
    $.ajax(
      url:url,
      type:'GET',
      data: {this: "that"},
      success: (data) =>
        successFunction(data)
      error: (errorData) =>
        errorFunction
      )
    )
  )
  initialParse: ((data) ->
    thePlayer = JSON.parse(data)
    //updatePlayerUi(thePlayer)
    @getScores(thePlayer)
  )
  getScores: ((thePlayer) =>
    getData('player/'+thePlayer.id+/'scores', @displayScores, @uhOh)
  )

  displayScores: (data) =>
    //updateScoreUi(data)

  uhOh: (errorData) =>
   // displayError(errorData)
)
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks @scott-helm! It's works fine, but... but really for of this problem is not elegant solution!!??

Comment: Well, as far as elegance goes, you can wrap the ajax call in a "controller" for lack of a better term, and have named methods that contain your ajax calls. These named methods could accept handler functions for success and error, and you could compose your behavior in that way.  I will update my answer.